# about optional chain usage & the corresponding consequence to app

Tags: swift

I know optional chain is like:

```
if let name = student.info?.name {
  // if student has info & info contains name, it comes here.
}
```

**Questions:**

**1.** But what is the difference between doing above and doing the following:

```
let name = student.info?.name
```

Is it so that the `let name` would be nil if `student` doesn't have `info` or if `info` doesn't contains `name`?

**2.** What would happen to app if `info` doesn't contain `name` with following code:

```
var student: Student? {
    didSet {
         // 'nameLabel' is an outlet for UILabel
        nameLabel.text = student.info?.name
    }
}
```

will app crash in above case if `student` doesn't have `info` or if `info` doesn't  have `name` when setting the `student` variable?

Comment: "I know optional chain is like: `if name = student.info?.name`" No, you don't know that. That code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @matt, that was my typo, now it should compile

Comment: Okay, great. Now my critique is that you are asking two completely unrelated questions. I've answered question 1, but question 2 should be deleted and you should ask it separately. (Even better, just _try doing_ question 2 and _see_ what happens! The universe isn't going to explode, you know. _Try_ it and _see_.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional chaining means that you can safely check the values of nested optionals. If any of the optionals in the chain is `nil`, the values are not checked further, the return value of the whole chain becomes `nil`. You need to mark all optional values with the `?` character in an optional chain, not just the last one, in your question you only marked the last optional.

The code in your question wouldn't actually compile, since when accessing properties of an optional, you need to either force unwrap it or use optional chaining.
`student!.info?.name` compiles, but results in a runtime crash if `student == nil`. `student?.info?.name` compiles and doesn't lead to a crash, but returns `nil` if either `student == nil` or `student?.info == 
nil`. `student.info?.name` doesn't compile, since you don't unwrap the optional `student` variable at all.

This is optional binding and you should use it in most cases when you need to work with optional values.

```
if let name = student?.info?.name {
  //name is non-optional here, so it can safely be used inside the if statement
}
```

If you use optional chaining without optional binding, your variable type will be optional as well:

```
let name = student?.info?.name //name is optional here
```

For your last question, the fact that `didSet` is called doesn't mean that `student` is not `nil`. In fact, the property observer will be called every time a value is assigned to the property and since `student` is optional, `nil` is a valid value, hence `student` can be `nil` inside the property observer. Moreover, even the fact that `student` has a non-nil value doesn't guarantee that `student.info` has a non-nil value as well. However, since `UILabel.text` has type `String?`, assigning a `nil` value to it doesn't lead to a crash unless later on you force unwrap `nameLabel.text`.

```
var student: Student? {
    didSet {
         // 'nameLabel' is an outlet for UILabel
        nameLabel.text = student?.info?.name
    }
}
```

For more information, have a look at [The Swift Programming Language Guide - Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) part.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is the most clear one in explaining what option chain is and what optional binding is, with very clear code snippet and explanations. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

1. If info property is nil, name will become nil. Otherwise name will be assigned name property of info. 
   Conclusion, "name" depends on the info property, not the info.name property.
2. The app won't crash, beacause UILabel.text is of optional type. text will be nil if info is nil, otherwise it will be info.name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access a variable in an object that is not defined as you do, your app will crash.

If info wasn't optional but name was, then it would be put nil value in the nameLabel.text, but your example will certainly crash.
You seem to know how to deal with this, but I'll add a solution for that :

```
var student: Student? {
    didSet {
        if let studentInfo = student.info {
            nameLabel.text = studentInfo.name
        } else {
            nameLabel.text = "unknown"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if let name = student.info?.name {
> ```
>
> But what is the difference between doing above and doing the following:
>
> ```
> let name = student.info?.name
> ```

A huge difference.

- The second one *perpetuates* optionality: `name` is still an Optional, and you still have the problem of unwrapping it safely, i.e. without crashing in case it happens to be `nil`.
- The first one *removes* optionality: if we dive into the curly braces, `name` is *not* an Optional, because the original Optional *has* been wrapped safely.

Answer (score 0):

A `?` mark, is like opening a pizza box to see if there is a pizza inside of it.

Pizza box, is optional variable. (A variable with `?`, ex. `var student: Student?`)
and the pizza is the student object it self.

Let's say you want to access the `name` of the `var student`. It's like you want a slice of pizza from the pizza. Because the pizza is in a box, you have to open the box first, same with optional variable, to access its member, you have to open it first.

But wait, as you open the pizza box, there is no pizza inside of it, and of course you can't have the slice pizza you wanted to eat. The same can be applied to the `var student`, because it's optional, after you open it up, it can be empty (`nil`).

That's why if you have `var student: Student?`, and you want to access `name` from `student`, you have to open it up first with `student?` followed by the member you want to access `student?.name`. Of course, if the student is `nil` the return value is `nil`.

**Question 1**

What's the different between `if let` and just `let`, well, `if let` is a conditional to ask if the object in the box exist? If there is an object, then do this.

```
if let name = student?.name {
    print(name)
}
```

from the above code, if `student` is not `nil` and just say the the var `name` contain `joe` then `joe` will be printed. But, if the `student` is `nil` then the `print(name)` is never get executed.

```
let name = student?.name
print(name)
```

The above code, remove the `if` statement, so this is not asking if the object is exist, but regardless the object exist or not, it want something. So if `student` is `nil`, of course the `name` will return `nil`, and we get `nil` printed in the debug view.

**Question 2**

You should first see if the `nameLabel.text` is optional. We can see from your code that `student` is optional, but we don't know if the `.text` is optional. Assign an optional into an optional is never a problem. If the variable is `nil` then the assigned var also become `nil`.

But if you assign an optional into a non optional variable, swift compiler will tell you that you can't do that, because if the optional variable is `nil` then the non optional variable will crash because it can't be `nil`